# How to properly place images on a webpage regardless of the size of window size?

Tags: html, css, image

I have two screens my laptop screen and my extended TV screen.

When I view my webpage through my laptop screen I see this.

[image]

However when I change the zoom or view webpage through my TV it looks like this.

[image]

For clarity I would like my images to be in the same position regardless of the size of the window. Thus the Android picture should always be underneath the contact button.

The images are spawned through CSS and is below. I believe that the HTML code is irrelevant since I just declare the links. (Those images are actually clickable)

```
   #Resume{ /* The MY Name Image */
 background-image: url(Resume_Button.png);
postion:relative;
display: block;
border: .25em solid #FF0004;
height:22em;
margin-top:10em;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: 200%; <!--For Removing the hyperlink (Not Clean) --> 
white-space:nowrap;
width: 31em;   
}

#Resume:hover{
 border: 1em solid #FF0004;
}


#Personal_Projects{ /* Android Button */
background-image:url(android-logo2.png);
postion:fixed;
background-position:right;
display: block;
height:18em;
margin-top:1.5em;
margin-left:55em;
border: 0.25em solid #FF0004;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
width:20em; 
}

#Personal_Projects:hover{
border: 1em solid #FF0004; 

}
```

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: What could you mean, "In the same position regardless of the size"? `position:relative;` and `position:absolute;` or using a percentage? Depending on your needs, you may have to use JavaScript. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Your problem is that you are positioning the elements at a certain point. That point will be the same regardless of screen size. It's like drawing a dot at 2 inches down and 4 inches over on a piece of paper. If the paper is 8.5x11 and 4.25x5.5, the dot will not be "in the same place"

Comment: If you want to position the images always in same position.. use percentage values like: `left: 50%` etc.

Comment: @PHPglue I mean regardless of the size of the browser window

Comment: Define "same position". Same on the right and left? Same from the top and bottom? Same percentage, from the left, or right?

Comment: @Hardy I try that know. Thank you

Comment: @PHPglue If you take a look at the Android logo on the second link. I would always like it below the contact button. However Hardy pointed out that it technically is in the same position because of I hard coded it.

Comment: @Hardy What position property tag should I use. Does it matter ?

Comment: You should use `position:relative`

Comment: @user126497 you should use `position:absolute` since position:relative just positions your element relative to it's static position.

Comment: If you have those tabs, which we cannot see in your first image by the way, set to a percentage, and you want it the "same" from the right side of the screen (thanks for not answering my question), then you'll want to use `margin-right:10%;` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Write Margin, Height and Width Properties values in Pixels rather than em.

Comment: This will not work because it is still hard coded. Switching to pixels will not solve this issue